# Скрыть колонку из грида

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scss

В общем суть такова:
Есть таблица, первая колонка - с чекбоксами, их отображение нужно только в конкретных случаях. Я сделал логику отключения колонки с чекбоксами через v-if и всё отлично работало, но ввиду некоторых нюансов сказали поменять на v-show. При простой замене v-if на v-show логика работать перестаёт, чекбоксы не скрываются (видимо подавляет element-ui). Мне подсказали, что можно доработать стили чтобы v-show работал, типа сделать 2 класса чтобы точно акцентироваться на конкретной колонке и там уже сделать display: none;
Сделал так:

```
<template>
  <div id="main-table">
    <el-table
        v-fixed-header
        :data="procedureData"
        style="width: 100%"
    >
      <el-table-column
          type="selection"
          width="50"
          :span-method="objectSpanMethod"
          class-name="first-row checkbox-row"
          v-show="isCheckboxHidden"
      >
```

стили:

```
<style lang="scss">
  #main-table {

    .first-row.checkbox-row {
      display: none;
    }
```

В итоге чекбоксы скрылись, но соседняя колонка встала на место колонки с чекбоксами, а ввиду маленькой ширины колонки весь текст поплыл.
Как мне донастроить стили чтобы колонка с чекбоксами скрывалась, а остальные элементы оставались в своих колонках, просто сдвигаясь влево?

UPD: добавил скрин
[image: display:none]

[image: visibility:hidden]

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
.first-row.checkbox-row {
  display: none;
}
```

Попробуй

```
.first-row.checkbox-row {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Помогло, правда осталось белое узкое поле на месте где была колонка. Но это уже что-то. Правда я заметил что v-show в отличии от v-if не поддаётся той логике которую я создал и по флагу тру\фолс оно не переключает видимость чекбокса.

Comment: visibility:hidden - скрывает , display: none - полностью отключает компонент, соответсвенно поэтому и осталось белое поле.

Comment: киньте скрин что у вас происходит при display:none;

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Это с visibility:hidden или с display:none

Comment: это дисплей нон. с хидденом в том месте где первая колонка белая фон просто. Идеально конечно бы добиться чтобы белый фон сдвигался.

Comment: Добавил скриншот c visibility:hidden

Comment: Почитал документацию по vue- мне только display: none вариант править, потому что v-show работает как раз с display:none

Comment: Я не понял так что у вас плывёт при display:none ?

Comment: на первом скриншоте текст с правой колонки вместился в колонку из-под чекбокса и естественно поплыл

Comment: Скиньте скрин как должно быть и что имеется сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что кому-то поможет без глубокого контекста, но решение такое:
(isCheckboxHidden - boolean)

```
  <el-table-column
                  type="selection"          
                  :width=" (isCheckboxHidden ? '1' : '50')"
                  :span-method="objectSpanMethod"
                  :class-name="'first row ' + (isCheckboxHidden ? 'hide-checkbox' : '')"
```

css:

```
.hide-checkbox {
  .el-checkbox {
    display: none;
  }
}
```